# Junit for Files google cloud storage services

Tags: java, junit, google-cloud-storage, junit5, powermockito

I am trying to read files from GCS. Following method I have created . I am using this method in some service layer. As some calls in this method are static and final, because of that my unit tests are failing.

Following is the code for GCS storage:

```
private Map<String, List<fclass>> getBulkFiles() throws IOException {
    Map<String, List<fclass>> mapOfFiles = new HashMap<>();
    List<fclass> validRecords = new ArrayList<>();
    List<fclass> invalidRecords= new ArrayList<>();
    // Get storage options in GCS for the project provided
    StorageOptions options = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(gcsConfig.getProjectId())
                                   .setCredentials(gcsConfig.getCredentials()).build();
    // Loop through the cloud storage and store the file details
    try (FileSystem fs = CloudStorageFileSystem.forBucket(gcsConfig.getBucketName(), CloudStorageConfiguration.DEFAULT, options)) {
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(fs.getPath(gcsConfig.getFeedFilePath()))) {
            for (Path path : ds) {
                prepareValidInvalidAsset(path, validRecords, invalidRecords);
            }
        }
    }
    mapOfFiles.put("VALID_RECORDS", validRecords);
    mapOfFiles.put("INVALID_RECORDS", invalidRecords);
    return mapOfFiles;
}
```

I am trying to write Junit tests for the same.
But Files.class is final and for `Files.newDirectoryStream(fs.getPath(gcsConfig.getFeedFilePath()))`
I am getting null pointer exception.

Looking forward for hearing from you all soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to mock final classes and you are using the Mockito framework, then you can use the library **org.mockito:mockito-inline**. This lib allows you to mock final classes.